# Reading an .xps file, why are bits of text being run together?

Tags: c#, xps

Given the other questions on here about .xps files I found Microsoft's library to do it.  My first attempt read the text out of the file but it's not right--the pieces of text do not correspond.

Consider the first line that I'm actually after:

The XPS viewer in Windows 7 correctly shows this as 9 columns:

```
1
1
B24
24
x
35 1/4
x 
24
U-U
```

However, the items in the file are (formatted for display):

```
144,169.12 = B24
50.56,169.12 = 1U-U
110.24,169.12 = 12424
356.64,169.12 = x35 1/4x
```

Field #1 has had #9 tacked on the end.  #2,#4 and #8 are merged into #3.  #5, #6 and #7 are merged into #4.  (Yes, you can't tell the 1's apart.  From looking at other lines I can.)  Every line is being mangled in exactly the same fashion.

Items #2 and #4 can be parsed anyway but #3 is ambiguous.

The relevant portion of the code that is producing this:

```
while (ContentReader.Read())
    if (ContentReader.Name == "Glyphs")
        if (ContentReader.HasAttributes)
        {
            String Text = ContentReader.GetAttribute("UnicodeString");
            String XText = ContentReader.GetAttribute("OriginX");
            String YText = ContentReader.GetAttribute("OriginY");
            Contents += XText + ", " + YText + " = " + Text + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

How do I actually get all 9 fields out of this?  Why are they being merged and not even in order?

Edit:  I extracted the raw file out of the .xps file.  What I'm getting is exactly what's in the file.  The only hint I get as to what's going on is that there is a field there, Indices that's simple on the ones that haven't been messed with and long on the ones that have.  Am I looking at some sort of deliberate obfuscation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with a similar situation.
My solution, *which I'm currently trying to improve on*, is this:

`String Indices = ContentReader.GetAttribute("Indices");`

Details on this attribute containing information on the glyph's 'advanced width' is found in 12.1.3 of ECMA-388 (OXPS standards)

https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-388.htm

Comment: Since I asked this I have figured out that the indicies give the offset of each character from the start point of the line.  **Generally** I can separate out fields by looking for too-wide gaps between characters but this isn't 100%.  95% of the problem has been solved by a new version of the program generating this that will export .RTF files, there's little I have to fish for in the .XPS files anymore.